# capybara not wait ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist, capybara-webkit

I get the following error in rspec + capybara + poltergeist:

```
given!(:user_owner) { create(:user) }
given!(:second_user) { create(:user) }
given!(:question) { create(:question, user: user_owner) }

describe 'as not question owner' do
  before do
    login_as(second_user, scope: :user, run_callbacks: false)
    visit question_path(question)
  end

  scenario 'can upvote just one time', js: true do
    first('a#question-upvote').click
    expect(first('div#question-score').text).to eq '1'
    first('a#question-upvote').click
    expect(first('div#question-score').text).to eq '1'
  end
```

Failure/Error: expect(page.first('div#question-score').text).to eq '-1'

```
   expected: "-1"
        got: "0"
```

When I insert sleep 1:

```
scenario 'can upvote just one time', js: true do
   first('a#question-upvote').click
   sleep 1
   expect(first('div#question-score').text).to eq '1'
   first('a#question-upvote').click
   sleep 1
   expect(first('div#question-score').text).to eq '1'
end
```

Test pass.

I understood that page not waited asynchronous request.
How can I rewrite test to start it to work well without sleeping?

P.S. Sorry for English.

Comment: you don't need to apologize about your English. It's pretty good. You're understandable, that's what matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're killing any waiting behavior by using the `eq` matcher. This is because once you call `.text` on a found element you have a String and  there is no way to reload/re-query that string when used with the `eq` matcher. If you want waiting/retrying behavior you need to use the matchers provided by Capybara with Capybara elements.

So instead of  `expect(first('div#question-score').text).to eq '1'` you should be doing

```
expect(first('div#question-score')).to have_text('1', exact: true) # you could also use a Regexp instead of specifying exact: true
```

Another thing to note is that `all`/`first` disable reloading of elements, so if the entire page is changing (or the element you are waiting for text on is being completely replaced) and the initial page had an element that would match the selector but you actually want the element from the second page (or replaced element) to be checked you shouldn't be using `first`/`all` - In that case you would want to use `find` with a query using the css :first-child/:first-of-type, etc type things (or equivalent XPath) to uniquely identify your element instead of returning multiples and picking one of them.  If it's just the value of the element being replaced asynchronously on the page then you did not to worry about it.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. You helped me again.